# Cannot Attach Debugger with Docker Containers in Visual Studio 2019 - Errors

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

I am trying to run the Visual Studio debugger using after building my containers with docker-compose. The containers build fine and start up and are all listed in the containers view.  The output windows shows everything to be fine and then issues 8 commands for each service:

```
========== Debugging ==========
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/dataapi$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
e2490aa5ec53
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/statisticsapi$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
275a0475c7f6
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/wellspacingapi$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
99a1b4c77f28
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/dataworkflowsapi$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
b900708dc919
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/griddingapi$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
6d05117e9f5a
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/apigatewayocelot$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
542dfca93543
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/identityserver$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
74b5552affaa
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/loginserverapi$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
c4ff67ab6a7a
```

I then get a "Microsoft Visual Studio" error dialog 8 times, one for each microservice, that says:

```
One or more errors occurred.

Failed to launch debug adapter.  Additional information may be available in the output window.

The operation was cancelled.

The program '' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

A picture of the dialog:

[image]

What's even more frustrating is that my colleague has the exact same machine and software and version of the software as me and it works for him.  My software version:

```
Visual Studio: 16.9.2
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88

dotnet --info:

.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.201
 Commit:    a09bd5c86c

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.4
  Commit:  f27d337295

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

I have researched other problems that are similar, but none of their resolutions have worked for me.  Any help is greatly appreciated!!